# Make Visual Studio Code IDE Recognize EJS Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, ejs

I am making a project in Nodejs with express framework i am using EJS as template engine, i use Visual Studio Code as a IDE.

I have a strange problem where when i use EJS variable inside `<script>` tag in same `ejs` file it renders correctly and woks as expected but Visual studio Code marks it an error saying `JS Expression Expected`

```
 <% 
    var date = matches.dateGMT;
    var matchDate = date.getTime();
  %> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var date = <%= matchDate %> ;
        var dateUntil = new Date(date);
        $('.match_time').countdown({until: dateUntil});
    });
  </script>
```

> Screenshot from IDE

[image]

**Any one has idea how to get rid of this error showing in Visual Studio Code.**

Comment: Visual Studio Code initially doesn't support EJS, but you can look at plugins

Comment: @Duoxx ....can you suggest any good plugin because last time used one it was clashing with existing rules of VSC and i had to uninstall it.

Answer (score 4):

I use VSCode for my Express applications as well. I have installed the JavaScipt EJS plugin by Digital Brainstem, and everything works fine.

Also, just a suggestion (as JS is not my first language), you can probably take the matchDate as an argument to the function and then wrap it around an event. It'll just increase the overall readability of the code. Rest is personal preference.

Comment: thanks that JavaScript EJS Plugin By Digital Brainstem really worked

Comment: update , the mentioned plug-in worked for this but started giving other problems